# How to add line numbers to file being edited in vi?

Tags: unix, vi

I have some text and I use `:number` in command mode to get number in each line and besides this I also want to have this number at saved output. What method/command can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the power of Unix utilities with the power of vi filtering. There are several utilities that number text files: [nl(1)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nl.html), but also cat(1) (assuming it supports the non-POSIX `-n` option). When you are in `vi`, run this command to filter the whole file through `cat -n`:

```
:%!cat -n
```

You could also use

```
:%!nl
```

but note that `nl` by default does not number empty lines, while `cat` does. To number all lines with `nl`, use

```
:%!nl -b a
```

Comment: perhaps, but `cat -n` isn't [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html).  The comment about `nl` seems okay.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Which is why I stated this as a parenthetical remark.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command [nl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nl).

i.e.

```
nl <in.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: there is not any vi's command so i can do it inside vi only ?

Comment: Cannot think of anything off the top of my head. Just use the command above. i.e. come out of vi, perform the command, go back into vi.

Comment: and it works and thank you . but it would be more convenient if there is command inside. anyway thanks man

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_line_numbers):

```
%s/^/\=printf('%-4d', line('.'))
```